# Compute the source code length of C functions

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

I want to partially automate grading of C code (ANSI C99) for a university course. One property I would like to compute is the **number of lines per C function** (optionally excluding blank and comment lines).

I am aware of several tools that can filter out blank lines and comment lines in a file, but that would only solve half my problem. I want to separate lines that belong to an **individual C function**.

I have been told a regex will not work. Is there a clever way to use the gcc preprocessor?

Comment: You could count the lines between a first `{` and the last `}`. A first means the start of a function, then stack each next `{` and match with its closing `}`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but that would not work if I have strings or comments with braces outside the function.

Comment: How is LOC count a good objective measure of anything? Any C program can be made into a one-liner.

Comment: @PSkocik For entry-level programmers, a common problem is that they write too long functions. I want an automated tool that can help me detect the submissions I should take a special look at.

Answer (score 3):

Clang has a switch for printing the syntax tree.

For example, if I run

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only lc.c
```

on

lc.c:

```
int main()
{


}

void f()
{
}
```

I get:

```
...
|-FunctionDecl 0x558d2c812890 <lc.c:1:1, line:5:1> line:1:5 main 'int ()'
| `-CompoundStmt 0x558d2c812970 <line:2:1, line:5:1>
 `-FunctionDecl 0x558d2c8129c8 <line:7:1, line:9:1> line:7:6 f 'void ()'
   `-CompoundStmt 0x558d2c812a68 <line:8:1, line:9:1>
```

If you write a script that extracts the line numbers from those depth=1 `CompoundStmt`'s that preceded by `FunctionDecl`'s (FunctionDecl + CompoundStmt == function definition) and subtract them, you get the line lengths of the your functions minus 1.

The preprocessor is little more than a tokenizer. You need a proper parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can address this problem in 2 steps:

- write a C parser that can remove comments
- instrument this parser to detect function names and bodies and count the meaningful lines of code. You should consider blank lines and lines consisting of braces and punctuation meaningless (`{`, `{`, `,`, `;`...). This will make your count less dependent on the coding style used by the programmer.

Here is help for the first step: a parser that strips comments:

```c
/* strip C comments by chqrlie */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* read the next byte from the C source file, handing escaped newlines */
int getcpp(FILE *fp, int *lineno_p) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) == '\\') {
        if ((ch = getc(fp)) != '\n') {
            ungetc(ch, fp);
            return '\\';
        }
        *lineno_p += 1;
    }
    if (ch == '\n')
        *lineno_p += 1;
    return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = stdin, *ft = stdout;
    const char *filename = "<stdin>";
    int ch, lineno;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if ((fp = fopen(filename = argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s: %s\n",
                    filename, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        if ((ft = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open output file %s: %s\n",
                    argv[2], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    lineno = 1;
    while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
        int startline = lineno;
        if (ch == '/') {
            if ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) == '/') {
                /* single-line comment */
                while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
                    continue;
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated single line comment\n",
                            filename, startline);
                    break;
                }
                putc('\n', ft);  /* replace comment with newline */
                continue;
            }
            if (ch == '*') {
                /* multi-line comment */
                int lastc = 0;
                while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
                    if (ch == '/' && lastc == '*') {
                        break;
                    }
                    lastc = ch;
                }
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated comment\n",
                            filename, startline);
                    break;
                }
                putc(' ', ft);  /* replace comment with single space */
                continue;
            }
            putc('/', ft);
            /* keep parsing to handle n/"a//"[i] */
        }
        if (ch == '\'' || ch == '"') {
            int sep = ch;
            const char *const_type = (ch == '"') ? "string" : "character";

            putc(sep, ft);
            while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
                putc(ch, ft);
                if (ch == sep)
                    break;;
                if (ch == '\\') {
                    if ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) == EOF)
                        break;
                    putc(ch, ft);
                }
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unescaped newline in %s constant\n",
                            filename, lineno - 1, const_type);
                    /* This is a syntax error but keep going as if constant was terminated */
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ch == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated %s constant\n",
                        filename, startline, const_type);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        putc(ch, ft);
    }
    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);
    if (ft != stdout)
        fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```